# ¿Cómo abrir un fragment distinto en para cada ítem de una lista?

Tags: java, android

Esto es lo que he probado, sin obtener los resultados esperados:

```
private final View.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0: //search//todo
                intent = new Intent(context, Fragment_Tabs.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
```

Y aquí es donde me quedo bloqueado totalmente con el (`View v`):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.R;
import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.RecyclerView.RecyclerViewClasses.Calendario;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter_Calendario extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Calendario.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Calendario> calendario;
    Context context;

    private final View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    // Adapter's Constructor
    public Adapter_Calendario(Context context, ArrayList<Calendario> calendario) {
        this.calendario = calendario;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Create new views. This is invoked by the layout manager.
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view by inflating the row item xml.
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // Set strings to the views
        final TextView textViewJornada = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_jornada);
        final TextView textViewFecha = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fecha);
        final TextView textViewHora = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_hora);
        final TextView textViewEquipo_local = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_equipo_local);
        final TextView textViewResultado_local = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_resultado_local);
        final TextView textViewResultado_visitante = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_resultado_visitante);
        final TextView textViewEquipo_visitante = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_equipo_visitante);
        final ImageView imageViewEscudo_local = (ImageView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_escudo_local);
        final ImageView imageViewEscudo_visitante = (ImageView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.tv_escudo_visitante);

        textViewJornada.setText("Jornada: "+calendario.get(position).getJornada());
        textViewFecha.setText("  El  "+calendario.get(position).getFecha()+"     ");
        textViewHora.setText("A las  "+calendario.get(position).getHora()+"  ");
        textViewEquipo_local.setText(calendario.get(position).getEquipo_local());
        textViewResultado_local.setText("   "+calendario.get(position).getResultado_local()+"   -   ");
        textViewResultado_visitante.setText(calendario.get(position).getResultado_visitante()+"   ");
        textViewEquipo_visitante.setText(calendario.get(position).getEquipo_visitante());

        Picasso.with(context).load(calendario.get(position).getEscudo_local())
                .placeholder(holder.view.getResources()
                        //.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_icon)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageViewImage);
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_icon)).into(imageViewEscudo_local);
        Picasso.with(context).load(calendario.get(position).getEscudo_visitante())
                .placeholder(holder.view.getResources()
                        //.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_icon)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imageViewImage);
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_icon)).into(imageViewEscudo_visitante);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return calendario.size();
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public View view;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            view = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Para que te podamos ayudar estaría bien que cambiaras el título por algo más explicativo, y que incluyeras en la pregunta una breve explicación de las "muchas cosas" que has probado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De lo que te he podido entender, al parecer quieres realizar esto:

```
private final View.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(context, Fragment_Tabs.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    context.startActivity(intent);        
}
```

Defines un layout con el contenedor para los Fragments: activity_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/style_background">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Ahora, tu clase resuelve que fragment utiliza de acuerdo a la posición (considerando que ese dato quieres enviar) seria algo así:

```
public class Fragment_Tabs extends AppCompatActivity {

   private FrameLayout frameLayout;
   private int position;    

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

       Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
       if (bundle != null){
           position =  bundle.getInt("position");
       }

       frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_fragment);

       switch(position){
           case 1:
               getPrimerFragment();
               break;
           case 2:
               getSegundoFragment();
               break;
           default:
               ......
       }
   }    

   private void getPrimerFragment(){
       Fragment fragment = new PrimerFragment();
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment)
            .commit();

   }

   private void getSegundoFragment(){
       Fragment fragment = new SegundoFragment();
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment)
            .commit();
   }

   .....

}
```

Comment: Rafelcf@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es definir un `Framelayout` donde se cargará tu `Fragment`, en este caso con el Id Contenido:

Al hacer click en un item de las lista inicias la variable F (`Fragment` F) y lo reemplazas en el contenedor.

```
 Fragment f=new FragmentInicio();
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment oldFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contenedor);
    if (oldFragment != null)
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .remove(oldFragment)
                .addToBackStack("tag")
                .replace(R.id.contenedor, f)
                .commit();
    else
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack("tag")
                .replace(R.id.contenedor, f)
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cero que no me explique bien, lo que quiero es abrir un fragment en cada item, si voy bien encaminado......

```
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
            default:
            case 0:
               intent = new Intent(Adapter_Calendario.this, Fragment_Tabs.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
               intent = new Intent(Adapter_Calendario.this, Fragment2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 2:
                intent = new Intent(Adapter_Calendario.this, Fragment3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }


    }

}
```

Creo que es esto pero no hay manera que lo consiga aqui dejo el tab que quiero abrir.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.MainActivity;
import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.R;
import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.RecyclerView.RecyclerViewClasses.Jornadas;
import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.Tabs.TabsAdapters.TabsDesignViewPagerAdapter;
import com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.Tabs.TabsUtils.SlidingTabLayout;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Fragment_Tabs extends Fragment {

    String urlPost;
    JSONObject jsonObjectDesignPosts;
    JSONArray jsonArrayDesignContent;
    ArrayList<Jornadas> designs;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    String[] designTitle, designExcerpt, designImage, designImageFull, designContent;
    int postNumber = 99;
    Boolean error = false;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    View view;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    ViewPager pager;
    TabsDesignViewPagerAdapter tabsDesignViewPagerAdapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence titles[] = {"J. Actual", "Plantilla", "Clasificacion"};
    int tabNumber = titles.length;
    int tabsPaddingTop;
    TypedValue typedValueToolbarHeight = new TypedValue();
    Toolbar toolbar;
    FrameLayout statusBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_design, container, false);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("INFO");

        //  Setup tabs
        setupTabs();

        return view;
    }

    public void setupTabs() {
        tabsDesignViewPagerAdapter = new TabsDesignViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), titles, tabNumber);
        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(tabsDesignViewPagerAdapter);
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(false);
        // Tab indicator color
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                //TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
                //getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorAccent, typedValue, true);
                //final int color = typedValue.data;
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.md_white_1000);
            }
        });

        // Setup tabs top padding
        getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, typedValueToolbarHeight, true);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                tabsPaddingTop = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(typedValueToolbarHeight.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()) + convertToPx(25);
            }else{
                tabsPaddingTop = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(typedValueToolbarHeight.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                tabsPaddingTop = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(typedValueToolbarHeight.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21){
                tabsPaddingTop = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(typedValueToolbarHeight.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()) + convertToPx(25);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                tabsPaddingTop = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(typedValueToolbarHeight.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }
        tabs.setPadding(convertToPx(48), tabsPaddingTop, convertToPx(16), 0);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    public int convertToPx(int dp) {
        // Get the screen's density scale
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
        return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```